# Is there a way to get the name of a key path as a string?

Tags: swift

So let's say I have a struct like so:

```
struct Foo {
    let value: Int
}
```

And thus I have a key path defined for `\Foo.value`:

```
let keyPath = \Foo.value
```

Is there any way to query the text name of a KeyPath at runtime?

I.e. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
print(name(of:keyPath)) // prints "value" or "Foo.value"
```

Comment: Why do you need the key of a key path as a string? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm bridging to SQL, and it would be very convenient to use the key path as a default name for the column